# Assert specific view returned from controller route

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel

Assuming I have a controller method that looks something like this:

```
public function someRoute()
{
    if(some condition) {
        return View::make('view1');
    }

    return View::make('view2');
}
```

How would I assert in my unit test that `view1` was returned as opposed to `view2`?  A colleague mentioned that if I can get the HTML response as a string then I can just use PHPUnit's `assertRegExp` against the returned HTML to match a given string only found in `view1`, but that doesn't seem right to me.

Is there a better way?  A deeper question may be should I even need to worry about which view is returned in my unit test or if I should just `$this->assertResponseOk()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing unit test with acceptance tests, so you have two options:

1) Split those tests to unit and acceptance, and use a tool like Codeception to help you do acceptance, which is way more elegant than PHPUnit for this kind of test. With Codecption you would do things like:

```
$I->amOnPage('/someUrl');

$I->see('John Doe');
```

2) Do what your friend told you to do.